# URLRequest failed on Notification Hub iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

The Azure Notification Hub is not registering to the server. I haven't changed anything in the code where it registers the device to the server. Earlier it worked fine, but not now.

Im getting this issue when run this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    SBNotificationHub* hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:HUBFULLACCESS notificationHubPath:HUBNAME];
    [hub unregisterAllWithDeviceToken:deviceToken completion:^(NSError* error){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [hub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:tags completion:^(NSError* error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Registerd for notification");
                }
            }];
        });
    }];
});
```

Here is the error:

> Error Domain=WindowsAzureMessaging Code=400 "URLRequest failed for  { URL: https://.servicebus.windows.net//Registrations/2044525541292942848-4457854038111768645-1?api-version=2013-04 } with status code: bad request" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=URLRequest failed for  { URL: https://.servicebus.windows.net//Registrations/2044525541292942848-4457854038111768645-1?api-version=2013-04 } with status code: bad request}

I have checked all certificates and profiles and everything is fine.

Comment: Did you check [request headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223261.aspx)? Did you try `api-version=2015-01`? Did you try `registrations` lower case?

Answer (score 0):

As [Create Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx) states about 400 response code:

> Invalid request body. The registration could not be created because the request was malformed.

Per my understanding, you could leverage [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and [Capture Traffic from iOS Device](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForiOS) for getting detailed error message, here is my test, you could refer to it:
[image]

Additionally, I assumed that you need to check the format of your tags. As [Routing and Tag Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx) states about **Tags**:

> A tag can be any string, up to 120 characters, containing alphanumeric and the following non-alphanumeric characters: ‘_’, ‘@’, ‘#’, ‘.’, ‘:’, ‘-’.